# Display HTML returned as JSON during AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

My AJAX call previously returned an array of data as JSON using "echo jason_encode(array)" in my PHP code and I then looped through the result in my script and built the HTML using the returned data before displaying.

Now I changed the code to build the HTML in my PHP code and I want to return the HTML string to my script and display the HTML but I have no idea how to get it working and I have looked at over a dozen examples on this site and others but no luck.

**PHP**

```
$html = '<tr><td><div class="dummy">This is some text.</div></td></tr>';
$arr[] = array('html' => $html);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

**Script**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.mashed_row a').click(function () {
            var link_id = $(this).attr('link_id');

         $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                   url: 'explode',
                   data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>', link_id},
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success : function(data) {
                       if(data)
                       {
                           var txt = data['html'];

                                $("#xarticletab").html("");
                                $("#xarticletab").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                                $("#comments").removeClass("hidden");
                       }
                   }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$("#xarticletab").html(data['html']);` Set the innerHTML of that element with data['html'].

Comment: Thanks Riggs, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think there is an error on your JS code: `link_id` alone.
on JS, you should define `key: value`. So, maybe  `'link_id': link_id` ?

> Correct typo: `{key1: 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}`

After, use console editor of your browser to know if there is any Javascript error.

Alternatively, you can play with javascript functions: `console.log(data);` or event `alert(data)`